# how to rollback a transaction using rollback command?

Tags: sql, rollback

I have deleted a record from my table and after executing rollback command it shows "command completed successfully" but when i check it using select statement the table is still looking empty? why ?
[image]

Comment: Show the query you got, including the begin and rollback of the transaction

Comment: How are you executing the query and transaction? Through a client app like VB? And what is your SQL platform? MySQL, SQL Server...?

Comment: I am executing on SQL Server and the transaction i have executed using BEGIN Transaction command

Comment: @JasonClark, just show some code!

Comment: BEGIN TRANSACTION delete from table; ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

Comment: Are you sure you have data in the table? In your picture there is no rollback, no select.... show us actual code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some database connection methods such as ODBC default to what's known as ["autocommit" mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131281.aspx) - that is, the database connection automatically issues a COMMIT after each statement is executed. [JDBC does the same thing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html). I cannot say if this is what's happening in your case, but if so there's no way to do a ROLLBACK. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback command  takes you back to the latest committed state of the table.I guess your delete query might have contained some statement that committed the change(deletion of record).

Comment: it means i can Rollback my transaction before I execute Commit command?

Comment: Yes you can.But like @BobJarvis said that in some cases "autocommit" mode is enabled. Hence after you deleted the record , perhaps the changes were committed and hence you're unable to undo the change using rollback command.

Answer (score 0):

Jason Clark,

I did a test using MySql and use the "begin", "delete" and "rollback", used the following SQL (an example):

> begin; delete from aluno where id = 1; rollback;

In PostgreSQL, SQL syntax is the same and also worked.

Are you sure you used the correct SQL? I might have been some mistake? Is it really necessary to use "begin transaction" instead of just "begin"?

I hope this helps!